# Sending commands via Telnet/TCP to web page (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, telnet

I'm new to node.js
To illustrate my question, I'll use an example:

- Client sends a command via telnet/tcp to socket server (ie 'telnet 192.168.0.10 8888' then 'showDiv1')
- Command is forwarded from server to a Web page
- depending on command, different  are displayed on the web page

There are plenty of examples on the node.js website, but it seems difficult to combine the sample scripts to produce the desired functionality above. Any ideas?

Comment: Telnet is not secure, so you will be exposing all your commands as well as your username and password to anybody capable of sniffing packets.

Comment: its on a private/closed network. it really is just a simple test to be able to present a webpage remotely

Comment: @austincheney http isn't secure by itself either!

Comment: @skjaidev but HTTP does require me to type out instructions to execute and if it asks me for my username or password I will drop the connection and go somewhere else.